# Call REST API using Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to call REST API using Spring & would like to know if there is any such implementation similar to what Jersey provides as shown below:

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.InvocationCallback;

public class FacebookService {

    private final WebTarget target = ClientBuilder.newClient()
        .target("http://graph.facebook.com/");

    public Future<FacebookUser> userAsync(String user) {
        return target
            .path("/{user}")
            .resolveTemplate("user", user)
            .request()
            .async()
            .get(new InvocationCallback<FacebookUser>() {
                @Override
                public void completed(FacebookUser facebookUser) {
                    // on complete
                }

                @Override
                public void failed(Throwable throwable) {
                    // on fail
                }
            });
    }
}
```

For eg, here Jersey provides completed & failed method that can be used to find if API call has failed or successful.

how do we do it with spring?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring provides AsyncRestTemplate and it provides call back functionality. Here is the detail. It is supported from 4.x onwards.

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.1.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/AsyncRestTemplate.html